# Get whole POST with JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML

Tags: development

In order to get the whole POST I do

```
$app        = JFactory::getApplication();
$jinput     = $app->input;
$data       = $jinput->getArray($_POST);
```

that works ok.

But I want to apply the filter JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML.

```
$data       = $jinput->getArray($_POST, JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML);
```

Does not work. I have tried several ways but at the ends the only one that works for me is:

```
$data       = JRequest::get( 'post', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML );
```

as JRquest is deprecated I wonder if there is another way to get the whole post in an array with JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML filter.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the rough equivalent. Retrieve unfiltered (`raw`) input and then filter it with custom filter instance:

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray(array(), null, 'raw');
$data = JFilterInput::getInstance(null, null, 1, 1)->clean($data, null);
```